# MEANING OF ERROR 1292 (22007): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'JAIN'

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
UPDATE STUDENT
    -> SET NAME='JAIN' AND MAJOR='BIOLY'
    -> WHERE MAJOR='BIO';
```

> ERROR 1292 (22007): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'JAIN'

Comment: Remove `AND` and try using `,` (comma) then let us know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an syntax error.

When more than one column to be updated use `,` instead of `AND`

So the query should be as

```
UPDATE STUDENT
SET NAME='JAIN', MAJOR='BIOLY'
WHERE MAJOR='BIO';
```